# Why does this module only work when I don't pass any arguments to the `$(window).resize()` callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, commonjs, duo.js

I'm trying to modularize my front-end javascript. I'm using duo.js, which allows you to use commonjs modules and compiles it all for use in the browser (not unlike webpack or browserify).

The code listens for a resize event and `.hide()`s or `.show()`s the navigation., but it only works when I don't pass any parameters to the anonymous function that I'm passing to `$(window).resize()` as a callback.

So in the module below, `$(window).resize(function() {}` works and `$(window).resize(function(toggle, navigation) {}` doesn't. Why is that?

Module code:

```
/**
 * External dependencies
 */

var $ = require('components/jquery');

/**
 * Correct menu visibility on window resize
 */

module.exports = function(toggle, navigation) {
  $(window).resize(function() { // this works
    // Always show navigation when resizing to a larger screen size
    if($(toggle).is(":hidden")) {
      $(navigation).show();
    };

    // Always hide navigation when resizing to a smaller screen size
    if($(toggle).is(":visible")) {
      $(navigation).hide();
    };
  });
};
```

Initialization:

```
/**
 * Local dependencies
 */

var navVisibility = require('../../lib/components-nav');

/**
 * Navigation visibility
 */

var toggle = '#Nav-toggle';
var navigation = '.Nav';

navVisibility(toggle, navigation);
```

Comment: Can you make a functional jsfiddle.net of your problem?

Comment: An event handler function, which is anonymous `function() {}` doesn't  accept arguments.
You can pass arguments to this function like described here https://forum.jquery.com/topic/pass-arguments-to-event-handler#14737000002242558

Comment: @Havenard, unfortunately not, since duojs compiles this code (and I can't do that via jsfiddle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous function which is created and assigned as a handler will be having access to the variables which are defined in the context where it was created.
So, what you have shown in the example above is correct and I see no problem with it.

**EDIT**

I have NOT tested the following, but you may want to try this

```
var t = toggle;
var n = navigation;
$(window).resize({ x : t , y : n }, function (e) {
    var msg = $(e.data.x).val();
    if($(e.data.x).is(":hidden")) {
       $(e.data.y).show();
    };

    if($(e.data.x).is(":visible")) {
       $(e.data.y).hide();
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok, so it doesn't work work when I *pass* arguments because event handlers don't take arguments. And it works when I *don't* pass arguments, because the anonymous function already has access to the variables that are available in the context in which it was created.